# How can this code produce a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault

I've created this function, and yet for most inputs, it seems to crash and give me a "Segmentation Fault: 11" error. For what inputs could the following code result in a segmentation error?

```
int cubic_runtime(int const * const data, int n)
{
    int max = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= n - 1; i = i + 1){
        for(j = i; j <=  n - 1; j = j + 1){
            sum = 0;
            for(k = i; k <= j; k = k + 1){
                sum = sum + data[k];
            }
            if(sum > max){
                max = sum;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Well, for example, any value for data which points to an illegal memory location. walk your examples with a debugger and you should see the answer immediately.

Comment: @johnelemans A debugger? Where can I find such a thing?

Comment: Kindly Provide the whole code.

Comment: @SurajJain That is the whole code. It's one function.

Comment: Where is the main ??

Comment: Give the whole code, i may have figured this , i just want to test somethig

Comment: Always post a [mcve]

Comment: @SurajJain Ok, well, pretend that the main just calls this function and inputs a bunch of different arrays.

Comment: @RothX I am Asking Because some time out of bound access of array cause Segmentation Fault, Can't You JUst Paste the code, also try to remove const and tell me what happened?

Answer (score 0):

One thing i can add to avoid seg faults is: Always validate/sanity-check the provided inputs. In this case value of 'n' can trigger potential fault. I think 'data' is fine because it is read-only and we are mere reading.